# Will updating my github repo master branch impact my working rubygem?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

I have a RubyGem(popular-deals) and a GitHub repo for that(https://github.com/HimaChitalia/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli). I made some changes to my code to refactor it and thinking of pushing changes to GitHub but I don't want to make any version change to my RubyGem right now.

My question is if I push my commits to the master branch, will it make any impact on my RubyGem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's fine to push updates to master, that's really the point of open source version control.

Most users will have set up their Gemfile source as [your project on RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/popular_deals/versions/0.1.0), so as long as you don't update that, it's fine.

A few developers might be pointing their Gemfiles to your Github (master branch or any other branch), maybe to get more recent functionality. That's the risk they're taking and you shouldn't feel obliged to make every master commit a stable release for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. You solved my problem!